# How can I build the OpenIAB unity package using gradle?

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I've got problems at building the OpenIAB unity package.
The `sdk.dir` is already set in the `local.properties` file.

This is the log:

```
Denniss-MBP:unity_plugin dennisxxx$ ../gradlew clean buildPlugin --info
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/Volumes/Daten HDD/Downloads/OpenIAB-Unity-Plugin-446cc2f310a2b13bcfdb93cf92ac5f9128d51f62/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/Volumes/Daten HDD/Downloads/OpenIAB-Unity-Plugin-446cc2f310a2b13bcfdb93cf92ac5f9128d51f62/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'OpenIAB-Unity-Plugin-446cc2f310a2b13bcfdb93cf92ac5f9128d51f62', project ':Unity Plugin', project ':library']
Evaluating root project 'OpenIAB-Unity-Plugin-446cc2f310a2b13bcfdb93cf92ac5f9128d51f62' using build file '/Volumes/Daten HDD/Downloads/OpenIAB-Unity-Plugin-446cc2f310a2b13bcfdb93cf92ac5f9128d51f62/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':Unity Plugin' using build file '/Volumes/Daten HDD/Downloads/OpenIAB-Unity-Plugin-446cc2f310a2b13bcfdb93cf92ac5f9128d51f62/unity_plugin/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':library' using empty build file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':Unity Plugin'.
> Configuration with name 'default' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.414 secs
Denniss-MBP:unity_plugin dennisxxx$
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Ran into a similar problem. I've asked one of the contributors for help, lets see when he responds.
In the meantime, if you don't have any custom changes in the code, you can download the unity package from [here](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB/releases)